# Conditions necessary for commutators [A,B]=[B,A]?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I know that normally for commutators that [A,B]=-[B,A] where A and B are operators.  But under what conditions does [A,B]=[B,A]?

Comment: You're talking about $[A,B] = AB - BA$? Then $[A,B] = [B,A] \iff [A,B] = 0$.

Comment: ...which says something nice about $A$ and $B$. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is always true that $[A, B] = -[B, A]$, if we assume that $[A, B] = [B, A]$, we see that

$$[A, B] = -[A, B]$$

so that $[A, B] = 0$. Hence, it is necessary and sufficient that $A$ and $B$ commute.